# How to show the distributive law holds for $C[0,1]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I want to show that $C[0,1]=S$ is a ring, and the last property I have left to show is that for $f(x),g(x),h(x) \in S$, $(f(g+h))(x) = (fg + fh)(x)$, where "multiplication" is function composition.

Comment: Multiplication is usually defined pointwise, ie $(f\cdot g)(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)$ for precisely the reason Jardel has pointed out below -- if we define the multiplication operation to be composition, distributivity fails, and we don't get a ring.

Comment: Thanks so much, I thought composition was the way to go but now I see it's not. :)

Answer (score 2):

If $C[0, 1]$ is the set of continuous functions in $[0,1]$, take, for example, $f(x) = x^2$, so 
$f \in C[0, 1]$. We have,
$$
(f(g+h))(x) = (g(x)+h(x))^2 = (g(x))^2 + 2\,g(x)\,h(x)+(h(x))^2,
$$
and
$$
(fg + fh)(x) = (g(x))^2 + (h(x))^2.
$$
Thus, in genereal,
$$
(f(g+h))(x) \neq (fg + fh)(x).
$$
I do not know if this is correct or if I could help you.